# Errors running MoSync example project on Java ME phones

Tags: java-me, mosync

I'm working on a prototype [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com) / MAUI application: it runs fine in my Android phone and in the emulators (MoRe / JavaME). Then I try to compile and run the program in a couple of old Java phones (Motorola V3i and LG KP500) but I cannot manage to make it work, so I tested the phones with the MoSync HelloMAUI example:

- On the LG (tested with several LG profiles) HelloMAUI runs but display only a blank screen (I saw [some MoSync forum entries](http://www.mosync.com/content/white-screen-lg-km-555) on LG phones about having poor or incompatible JavaME support)
- On the Motorola v3i (compiled with the V3I profile) HelloMAUI stops with an "Application Error"

I'm a little disappointed on that, because the selling point I saw on MoSync was the support to this kind of old mobile phones. I'm developing an application to collect data, and this kind of old phones are cheaper and more rugged than recent Android phones, then I was trying to have a single codebase to all the devices:

- Did any of you had a good experience compiling and running an MoSync->JavaME application for this kind of old mobile phones? (not on the JavaME emulator, that works fine)
- If so, can you post what phone brand and model that worked fine in your particular case?
- I have no previous experience compiling Java ME applications, and saw several complains in the MoSync forum about incompatibilities among the Java implementations of several mobile devices that threatens the "Write Once, Run Anywhere" mantra. Is that the case? Maybe I'm naive but expected that a JAR/JAD that ran fine on the J2ME emulator can be deployed without major concerns over different phones.

Comment: Which Java ME Device Profile did you choose? http://www.mosync.com/documentation/manualpages/device-profile-database

Comment: @TelmoPimentelMota: I use the Motorola-v3i/JavaME1 profile and several LG Kxxxx/JavaME1 profiles

Comment: Maybe older versions of MoSync will have a better support for these devices. What version have you used?

Comment: @TelmoPimentelMota: i'm using MoSync Version 3.0.2 / Build date: 120523-1405.

Comment: Can you try an older version?

Answer (score 2):

I use mosync for developing some basic apps for my nokia x1 phone. and it was great.

I also run a lot of examples (not nativeUI) of mosync SDK on my phone. just "camera demo" seems has a some kind of bugs.